# Reflect updates to values in a Cell Table

Tags: gwt, celltable

I have a paginated table rendering my elements.

Now one of the elements of that type are updated by the server (by some other source). A message is received on the client that that element is updated (I have the object).

How do I reflect this on the table?

I think if I could just get the row for that element I'd be done.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you can simply call `refresh` on the DataProvider that backs your table.

But if your table is very complex, you can call

```
table.redrawRow(i);
```

where `i` is the index of your updated object in the list backing the DataProvider.

Comment: Problem is I don't know which row the updated value is in and I'd rather not update everything

Comment: refresh does not cause the entire table to be redrawn, so there is little downside.

Comment: Row is the same as the index of your object in the List backing DataProvider.